# Graded Ring Category vs Ring Category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

I know that in Ring Category we have:

-Objects: Rings.

-Arrows: Ring homomorphisms.

I do not know which are the objects and arrows in Graded Ring Category. 
In general, which is the definition of Graded Ring Category?

P.S. I need it in order to see why it makes a difference to take inverse limit in this two categories. (I am working in symmetric functions vs symmetric polynomials. Do not see the difference between this two concepts.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A graded ring can mean a few different things, but it's usually a sequence of abelian groups $R_i$ together with multiplication maps $R_i\otimes R_j\to R_{i+j}$ satisfying associativity, with a unit element $1\in R_0$. A morphism of graded rings is a sequence of abelian group maps respecting multiplication and unit.